What's the name of this quite old italian love movie?
I am looking for an italian (quite old, maybe from the 80 or 90, not quite sure) love story movie. 
It is a forbidden love story (one of them, maybe the man is rich and his parents don't agree with the marriage) set near a lake (one of the biggest in italy).
Eventually they get married and they have a daughter (called Maria as I remember - I might be wrong) and her grandmother decides to visit them. 
She brings the girl a wooden boat, Maria goes to the lake to play with it and eventually she drowns and dies. Her father arrives during the evening and finds out she is dead. 
